# Smallest Enclosing Circle

Tags: java, geometry, dynamic-programming

We were given an assignment https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr09/cos226/assignments/circle.html, and I did it, and all the test cases that are listed on this site went through my code that I wrote . But when I myself wrote the test cases for the code (which will be in the repository) half of it failed, as the correct code I took the code from https://www.nayuki.io/res/smallest-enclosing-circle/SmallestEnclosingCircle.java. Then I realized that I misunderstood the essence of the task a little; it was said to find the smallest possible Circle, but I just found one of the options that could be created. How can I improve the code so that the test cases run correctly without changing my code too much. Link to my code: https://github.com/Imangali-ang/Smallest-Enclosing-Circle.git

Comment: This question is probably better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hardillb: I do not agree. Code review is for improving code *without changing the results*

Comment: Could you extend your question with a description of your code's algorithm?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code here in the question as a [mcve]. Links can break, and the code pointed to can change (especially on github!) making the question useless for others with similar problems.